# C - Windows Exception Handler Invalid Handle

Tags: c, windows, winapi, exception

I have a problem about managing an exception. In my code I put hIn = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE to test the exception, and "null" is a non existing file. My piece of code is

```
__try
      {
             hIn = CreateFile (_T("null"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
             hIn = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
             ReadFile (hIn, buffer, BUF_SIZE*sizeof(DWORD), &nIn, NULL);
      }
    __except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_INVALID_HANDLE ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
      {
          _tprintf (_T("-> Error OPENING FILE <-\n"));
          return -1;
      }
```

I don't understand why it doesn't catch the exception. What is the problem?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__except` block is never entered because `ReadFile` does not throw exceptions.

Remember that the Windows API is agnostic of programming language and needs to present an interface that can be consumed by any programming language. And not all languages have support for exceptions, and even those that do use different mechanisms. So for an API like the Windows API, throwing exceptions is simply not an option.

Both of the API calls in your question indicate errors by their return values. You need to check these return values and act accordingly. Not all functions report errors in the same way so you need to pay close attention to the documentation for each API function that you call.

Answer (score 1):

The C-function (Win32 API) `ReadFile()` doesn't normally throw an exception. Instead check return value of `ReadFile` and if **FALSE**, call `GetLastError()` to get the error code.

Have you btw enabled SEH ? See compiler switch /EHsc

[see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The same applies to `CreateFile()` as well, which the OP also thinks is going to throw an exception. `GetLastError()`, not `GetLatestError()`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, your `__except` does not catch an exception because there is no exception being raised in the first place.  You need to check return values and error codes instead:

```
hIn = CreateFile (_T("null"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    _tprintf (_T("-> Error %u OPENING FILE <-\n"), GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
...
ReadFile (hIn, buffer, BUF_SIZE*sizeof(DWORD), &nIn, NULL);
...
CloseHandle(hIn);
```